# "Changes made in project 'X' will not be applied while the application is running" even when the application is not debugged anymore

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2019

That green squiggly underlining for lines that have not yet have been compiled (because I need to restart the application first) does not go away when I have stopped the debugger.

Why?

[image: Green squiggly underlines]

(they seem to disappear when I debug the application again)

## edit

[image]

When I click on "show potential fixes", nothing happens

Cleaning or removing bin+obj seems to do nothing

Comment: Did you "Detach" (which won't end the process) or "Stop Debugging" (which will stop the process)?

Comment: Stop debugging (red square)